# How to add textbox dynamically to WPF usercontrol. .?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How to add textbox dynamically(as per some conditions) to WPF usercontrol. .?

WPF usercontrol will be used in Winforms application...!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your UserControl, you need some container that can have multiple children, such as a StackPanel, a Grid, etc.

As the first step, you create your new control:

```
Dim myTextBox As New TextBox() With { .Text = "Hello World", ... }
```

Then you add it to the container:

```
myStackPanel.Children.Add(myTextBox)
```